# Post video on YouTube from Google App Engine site on behalf of that site, not the user

Tags: java, google-app-engine, youtube

I am looking for the solution on hosting the videos of my site on YouTube. The issue I see is that from the documentation on YouTube API it seems that the videos will be posted on the users behalf, not from my site.

The users are going to be moderators, so they will publish the content. It seems easy to add what they have uploaded to the web-site. But the video would remain owned by them and they can delete it from YouTube directly using their account.

Could anyone sugges any API for this? Is there a way to embed some account into the webapp and post on behalf of that account? It seems like Client YouTube authentication could do the thing, but it goes through deprecation now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically YouTube (or any other video hosting service) are not encouraging people to upload videos on behalf of somebody else for many reasons. One of them is that lots of privacy issues are arising and if they are going to upload something copyrighted you will get the blame since you want to sign them as if you were uploading them on your own. You might risk having your own account banned, because of some violation of YouTube terms and conditions of somebody else's fault.

The best way to avoid that having the users to upload videos on they behalf and simply giving them all the tools to do that through your service, but still they are uploading the video under their own name. That also protects your users as well, for example, if they would like to remove it at one point, they don't have to ask you to do that or they are not sure if they will be able to have the control of it since there is no real connection of who owns the video.

Comment: The users in my case are content managers, so they do not own the video. Plus it means that one user cannot delete the video of another user, but this is required for content managers

Comment: @user1485936 all you have to do is to keep track of who is posting what, and who is the content manager. The only difference is that the videos are hosted on YouTube under their own names..  who is controlling the videos that were posted on your site is another story!

Comment: If they all use their own Gmail accounts for authentication I don't see a way for some "superuser" to control posted videos

Comment: @user1485936 so you are saying if I'm going to upload a video on youtube and post it on your site.. you want to be able to delete that video from YouTube?

Comment: I am saying that if there are three full-time hired content managers posting video to my site, then this video needs to remain there until that site decides to remove it, but until the user decides to remove it.

Comment: hmm.. then you could enable I guess YouTube for Apps and having your managers create accounts using your own domain and eventually if they are going to be fired or something.. you are able to reset the password and take over..! If I understood it correctly.. either case the user who is uploading ideally should use their own credentials.. not shared ones.. or using some tricks in the backend to store a permanent sessions and stuff...

Comment: I will try this suggestion. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Using OAuth they should all authenticate using the Developer Key and thus, the same account.

https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_protocol_authentication

Comment: When I look here https://developers.google.com/youtube/2.0/developers_guide_java#Updating_and_deleting_videos, it says "The authenticated user must be the owner of the video that is being deleted.". This does not really fit my model, because I content manager cannot edit videos posted by others